# AS3 - Allow Forward Slash In Input Text?

Tags: actionscript-3, input

I'm trying to allow forward slashes to be entered in my input text field through this code:

```
myInputField.restrict = "A-Za-z.\\-\\/";
```

The above text field should allow upper case letters, lower case letters, periods, hyphens and forward slashes.  However, I can't seem to permit the forward slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pasted your code and it works as intended. I can write forward slashes without problem. Have you checked if the glyph is embedded? (in case you're embedding fonts, that is).

I'd write your code like this, though:

```
myInputField.restrict = "A-z.\\-/";
```

Since you don't need to escape forward slashes.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to escape the forward slash. Only `-` `^` and `\`.